# Convertir Json a Diccionario<string,object> c#

Tags: c#, json, web, blazor

Tengo una aplicación Blazor WASM en la que hago una petición mediante HttpClient con el método POST de la siguiente manera:

```
var respuesta = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<List<Asistencia>>("api/asistencia", lista);
```

El controlador por su parte me devuelve la respuesta como un diccionario de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> Registra(List<Asistencia> asistencia)
{
 return await Task.FromResult(_servicioAsistencias.RegistrarAsistencias(asistencia).Result);            
}
```

Ahora bien, hasta este punto toda la lógica de operación y respuesta es correcta, la API devuelve la información como un diccionario de objetos (que en este caso vienen siendo listados)

Ahora, cuando se hace el llamado la respuesta en el lado del servidor la recupero de la siguiente manera :

```
if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
 Dictionary<string, object>? myDictionary = new();

 var content = respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Ahora el valor de 'content' se muestra como un json, dado que fué así como se hizo la petición desde el POST y luce de la siguiente manera:

```
{
"Errores": [],
"Ids": [{
    "idEmpleado": "297",
    "hora": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "nombre": null,
    "departamento": null,
    "lector": null,
    "evento": null,
    "tipo": null,
    "rutaImagen": null
 }]
}
```

Ahora bien, eso es un diccionario que se armo de dos listas:

```
List<AsistenciaErrores> errores; //Omitan la inicialización, no es el caso la cuestión
List<Asistencia> ids; //Omitir la inicialización
```

Para luego armar el diccionario así:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new();

myDictionary.Add("Errores", errores);
myDictionary.Add("Ids", ids);
```

Ya investigué pero la deserealización no me funciona adecuadamente:

```
myDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(content);
```

Habiendo aclaro como es que se estructuró, lo que yo necesito es que cuando es convertido a Json, yo en la respuesta (del HttpResponse) quiero volver a tener la misma estructura o valga la redundancia **convertir de Json a Dictionary<string,object>**, para despues yo vaciar los objetos en sus respectivas y diferentes clases con:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> key in myDictionary)
{
  if (key.Key == "Errores")
     errores = key.Value as List<AsistenciaError>;

  if (key.Key == "Ids")
     ids = key.Value as List<Asistencia>;
}
```

El problema es que Blazor me arroja en la consola el siguiente error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BlazorWebVasti.Client.Pages.Index.RegistrarAsistencias() in E:\TeamFoundation\Blazor Web Vasti\BlazorWebVasti\Client\Pages\Index.razor:line 99
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

Ya debugueando ni siquiera entra al for each a iterar, y antes de que alguien me diga que porque no uso NewtonSoft.Json desde ya les digo que no quiero depender de ningun otra librerira externa, tampoco deseo No mandar un diccionario como respuesta en Json porque SI o SI lo necesito. Agradecería mucho de su ayuda. Es una app blazor web assembly (Cliente, Servidor y Shared) .NET 6.

**EDIT** (Segunda actualización)

La clase Asistencia:

```
public string? IdEmpleado { get; set; }
public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
public string? Nombre { get; set; }
public string? Departamento { get; set; }
public string? Lector { get; set; }
public string? Evento { get; set; }
public string? Tipo { get; set; }
public string? RutaImagen { get; set; }
```

Comment: Favor publica la clase Asistencia y AsistenciaErrores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

El acierto de Yussef era correcto, el nombre de las propiedades de la clase deben estar en mayúsculas o todas minúsculas o bien la primer letra en mayúscula sin tener ninguna otra en el medio, por lo que de IdEmpleado lo tuve que cambiar a Idempleado, de esta manera cuando el json arma la cadena se recupera en el servidor como idempleado, por lo que ahora ya no se pierden los valores al hacer  la deserialización quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Class Asistencia
{
  Public string? Idempleado { get; set; }
  ... // demás propiedades
}
```

Y en el lado del servidor quedó así:

```
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

var content = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AsistenciaRespuesta>(content, jsonSerializerOptions);
```

Gracias por el apoyo a Yussef!!

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte.  Valoro mucho los buenos comentarios que hiciste hacia mí, este tipo de comentarios me alegran el día, así que pensaba no escribir esto. Pero después pensé que sería bueno te dieras cuenta que el cambio de la "aceptación" de tu pregunta podía considerarse descortés. La aceptación de la respuesta implica que esta ha sido de ayuda a resolver el problema, no es la respuesta exacta (que en este caso era imposible). te dejo un enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Muchas gracias por enseñarme un poco sobre la comunidad, procuraré en el futuro ser un poco mas acertivo en las reglas, lo único que busco es que si alguien mas tiene o pudiera tener el mismo problema, sepa donde está ubicado la solución al verdadero problema y que deba inspeccionar lo demás para comprender. He recibido tu ayuda últimamente y me alegra saber que puedo encontrar ayuda de tu parte.

Comment: Se por experiencia propia que la reglas de este sitio son a lo menos ambiguas (yo no llevo mucho tiempo acá). Por eso decidí dejar el mensaje, porque el que responde dedica tiempo y solo recibe a cambio ese premio imaginario que son los punto. Por otro lado, lo que entiendo, es que la mejor respuesta se ve a través de los votos este es el índice para la comunidad, pero la aceptada es la que ayudó al OP (el que preguntó) a resolver su problema....SALUDOS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hacer esto no funciona, porque object queda como json

```
string json = $$"""{ "Errores":[],"Ids":[{ "idEmpleado":"297"}]}""";
var respuesta = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
List<Asistencia> asitencia = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Asistencia>>(respuesta["Ids"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(); // System.Text.Json.JsonElement
```

Entonces habría que volver a convertir

```
string json = $$"""{ "Errores":[],"Ids":[{ "idEmpleado":"297"}]}""";
var respuesta = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
List<Asistencia> asitencia = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Asistencia>>(respuesta["Ids"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(asitencia[0].idEmpleado); // 297
```

Que es lo mejor? Crear una clase respuesta

```
public class Respuesta{
    public List<Asistencia> Ids { get; set; }
    public List<AsistenciaError> Errores { get; set; }
}
```

```
string json = $$"""{ "Errores":[],"Ids":[{ "idEmpleado":"297"}]}""";
var respuesta = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Respuesta> (json);
Console.WriteLine(respuesta.Ids[0].idEmpleado); // 297
```

Comment: Yussef tu respuesta me parece bastante sofisticada, voy a intentar la opción de la clase respuesta a ver que consigo, aunque talvez me adelante, lo que yo necesito es recuperar todos los valores no solo un conteo (de ambas clases, dicho de otra forma de ambos objetos contenidos en el json), muchas gracias por el apoyo, probaré a ver que tal me va =) =D

Comment: Lo del conteo era solo para mostrar que la conversión ha funcionado sin errores, ahora me doy cuenta que no fue el mejor ejemplo de comprobación, editaré para colocar algo mejor. Por otro lado, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así lo consideras

Comment: Lo acabo de comprobar y me trae nulos, los conteos estan bien, pero al deserealizar en la clase respuesta por ejemplo en Asistencias la propiedad IdEmpleado deberia ser 297 pero en debug in runtime el valor de "respuesta" (en tu ejemplo) me recupera todo nulo no acabo de comprender por que =(

Comment: En cuanto a las clases el codigo de ejemplo lo escribi a mano solo tengo una clase llamada AsistenciaErrores, gracias por darte cuenta del error (tipografico)

Comment: mm.. Edita tu pregunta y publica las clase Asistencia para poder recrear el asunto

Comment: Ya edite y agregué unas capturas de pantalla, porque como puedes ver antes de deserializar en la clase respuesta el contenido del json esta bien, es si no hasta despues cuando intento iterar en la propiedad de la lista de asistencias que los valores se pierden.

Comment: @Berlín No veo las capturas :S

Comment: aahhh editaste mi respuesta

Comment: Como que no?? si yo las puedo ver jajaja las subi a imgur, haber esta es una https://imgur.com/a/Tqpt9zJ y la otra https://imgur.com/a/aRb86X8

Comment: Jajajaj es verdad jaja que torpe, una disculpa!!

Comment: Pero, lo que te estoy pidiendo es la clase Asistencia, porque quiero ver los tipo de datos, para recrear el asunto

Comment: @Berlín En todo caso sospecho que tu problema está en el nombre de las propiedades, fíjate que el JSON viene con minúsculas y tú las tienes con mayúsculas. Ejemplo idEmpleado vs IdEmpleado

Comment: Ya edite mi post original con la clase asistencia, en cuanto a lo del nombre de las propiedades, ese no creo que sea el problema, porque el json asi lo arma recupera el sistema yo no meto mano en eso, ahora si quieres te puedo enseñar el código de la lógica de armado.

Comment: Y otra cosa que veo, lo que tu me sugeriste ayer sobre lo del count, ya vi que me está contando solamente los dos objetos (listas) no los elementos de cada lista, es decir que si yo no le mando ningun objeto a la lista Errores el count es 0 pero si le meto dos objetos a la lista Asistencias me sigue contando 1 y eso no me sirve

Comment: Yussef lo consegui hermano , checa la respuesta que publiqué gracias a ti por supuesto.